# PHP MySQL INSERT query not inserting all values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have this variables :

```
$cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlentities($_GET["cliente"]));
$metatickt = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlentities($_GET["metatickt"]));
$metaext = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlentities($_GET["metaext"]));
$metaenc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlentities($_GET["metaenc"]));
$uf = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlentities($_GET["estado"]));
```

And I'm trying to do this query :

```
$queryInst = "INSERT  meta_control (mes,cliente,meta_exit,meta_tickt,meta_enc,uf)"
          . " VALUES (MONTH(NOW()),'" . $cliente . "','" . $metaext . "','" . $metatickt . "','" . $metaenc . "','" . $uf . "')";
 mysqli_query($conn, $queryInst);
```

But when I check my db the only column that is not NULL is `mes`. What could be the cause to this?

Comment: Consider using a prepared statement instead of manually embedding strings in a query.  It will prevent SQL injection and make it harder to improperly escape strings.

Comment: I will , but first I need this to work properly

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the values before running, for instance `$uf` and see what it is showing? I would assume it's the values as "mes" is the only one your not pushing variables through too.

Comment: Since `mes` is the only value that gets inserted correctly, and is the only value you don't grab from `htmlentities`, your `$_GET` values must be messing up somehow.

Comment: Are those values coming from a form? If so, you'd likely want `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: The ´var_dump()´  returns the correctly values of the variables. If I pass some constant value to the query it wont work either

Comment: Changing the `$_GET` to `$_POST` worked just fine. Tnx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use proper query.  `INSERT INTO`

```
$queryInst = "INSERT INTO meta_control (mes,cliente,meta_exit,meta_tickt,meta_enc,uf)"
              . " VALUES (MONTH(NOW()),'" . $cliente . "','" . $metaext . "','" . $metatickt . "','" . $metaenc . "','" . $uf . "')";
mysqli_query($conn, $queryInst);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an SQL error.
You should check for such errors using `mysqli_error($conn)` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. In this case you probably have an error caused by the absence of the `INTO` keyword in your SQL query, which should be `INSERT INTO ....`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html